# Flask - Pre-populate Fields from a text file

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am looking for a simple way to pre-populate fields of a form with data from a text file.

Here are my imports:

```
#For Flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, redirect, url_for, send_file 
#For Web Form
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField, SelectField, RadioField, IntegerField, DateTimeField, DecimalField, FloatField
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import re #For Regex
```

I have the following class for my form:

```
class MainForm(Form):
    #Regex
    reEmail_comp = re.compile('^.+@.+\..+$')
    reJobname_comp = re.compile('[^\s]+[\w]+$')

    #Form Fields
    familyname = TextField('Family Name:',
    validators=[validators.DataRequired()])

    firstname = TextField('First Name:',
    validators=[validators.DataRequired()])

    email = TextField('Email:',
    validators=[validators.DataRequired(),
    validators.Length(min=3, max=51),
    validators.Regexp(regex=reEmail_comp)])

    # Copy List of Job Templates 
    list_job_name = list_job_templates

    # Create List of Tuples
    choices_list = list(zip(list_job_name,list_job_templates))

    # Generate string to be evaluate as analyses Radiofield
    radio_string = ("RadioField('Analysis Type:',"
    "validators=[validators.DataRequired()],choices="+str(choices_list)+")")

    # Attribute value to element as a variable
    locals()["analyses"] = eval(radio_string)

    jobname = TextField('Job Name:',
    validators=[validators.DataRequired(),
    validators.Length(min=3, max=100),
    validators.Regexp(regex=reJobname_comp)])

    jobdescription = TextAreaField('Job Description:',
    validators=[validators.Optional(),
    validators.Length(min=0, max=10000)])
```

And the following view:

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = MainForm(request.form)

    print(form.errors)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        familyname=request.form['familyname']
        firstname=request.form['firstname']
        email=request.form['email']
        analyses=request.form['analyses']
        jobname=request.form['jobname']
        jobdescription=request.form['jobdescription']
        if jobdescription == "":
            jobdescription = "No Description"
        nextpage=request.form['submit'] #Get submission button value

        if form.validate():

            #Print Temp file
            print("||".join(["Family Name={}".format(familyname),
                    "First Name={}".format(firstname),"E-Mail={}".format(email),
                    "Analyse={}".format(analyses),"Job Name={}".format(jobname),
                    "Job Description={}".format(jobdescription)]),
                    file=open(submission_dir+"temp1", "w"))

            #Redirections following which button has been clicked
            if nextpage == 'Continue to Submission':
                return redirect(url_for('nextpage'))
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('nextbis'))

        else:
            flash('Error: Please make sure that all the fields are correctly filled.')


    return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

The user has access to the form and can fill it.
As you can see in the view there is a step during which all information are stored in a temporary "temp1.txt" file once the user submits its information.
What I would like to do is to give the user the option to go back to this form in case he would like to modify an information he previously submit.

And to simplify this, I would like the form to display the same fields, but this time, pre-populated with the information found in the temporary text file from the previous submission.

How can I do that in a simple way ?

Answer (score 2):

If you created a form and populated it from request, then same can be done with file values.

```
form = MainForm(read_file_in_correct_format())
```

where `read_file_in_correct_format` method returns object {fieldname:value}. It would be probably better to save as JSON so you can easily parse it and support more complex structures.

All you have to do is correct initialize form based on `request.method`

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # so if form is submitted, populate it from request
        form = MainForm(request.form)
        ...
    else:
        # if we are just viewing form, then try to load stored values from temp1.txt
        form = MainForm(read_file_in_correct_format())
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand.  
When the user load the form, none of the field should be pre-populated.  
It should be the case after a first submission in case the user go back to this page.  
I don't understand in your example what should I do of the  `form = MainForm(request.form)` that I had before if I replace it by what you suggest.  
If you can be more precise in your answer that would be helpful.  
(Thank you for the tip about JSON  I will check that!)  
btw I edited so that you can see my imports, Form is imported from wtforms.

Comment: Updated example.. makes more sense?

Comment: Yes this is more clear, thank you!
Shouldn't I create an other class that MainForm ? since the class need to contain the function needs to read the json file and generate the fields already filled with default values defined in the json file form the previous submission.
Or should I also update my existing Class MainForm ?

Comment: I think your answer is working, but it does not work for me. how can I just test it simply on "familyname" field for example  ?
I tried this:
    `else:`
        `form = MainForm(request.form)`
        `form.familyname.process_data = "string_to_display in the field"`
But it does not work.

Comment: So finally I achieve to do what you were thinking about, but it is only partially working, I explain: 

After reading documentation I decided to create a function `read_file_in_correct_format()` which return a MultiDict object (because a simple dict such as {fieldname:value} is not supported, I had an error with getlist ).
I am sayingit is partially working because despite I still have none of my TextField prepopulated, my RadioField is well pre-selected for the previous analysis selected.
I think I am really close to get it, if you have any idea for TextField, let me know.

Comment: since the question changed a bit, I created a new Issue on stackoverflow. you can find the new code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753817/flask-prepopulating-wtform-with-multidict-does-not-work-for-textfields-only-r

if you need anything else, please let me know. Cheers.